# Anything wrong with NOT signing a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, strongname

One of my colleagues is very keen on signing assemblies. He literally tries to sign anything. Even when we use assemblies from Microsoft that are not signed, he will take the source code, sign it and then ask other developers to use his copy instead.

I can understand the basic idea behind signing an assembly: to ensure a particular assembly is not compromised by some dodgy hacker. So if we are a software development company, we should sign our assembly before releasing some .NET library to our customers.

However, we primarily develop web applications for our own use here, and I just can't see the point of signing every single assembly we use.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is worth noting some confusion here, "digital signatures" (which have a security purpose) and "Strongly named assemblies" which are a fix to dll hell and aid the GAC to link to libraries. Using one or another is similar and both can be spoken of in terms of signing an assembly. It seems like some posters are thinking of one and others are thinking of another or both.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Signing assemblies that are used within a trusted environment sounds like overkill to me.

An interesting point on signed assemblies is that they are slightly slower to load than unsigned assemblies, as they must be cryptographically verified.

In order to sign an assembly, any assemblies it depends upon must also be signed.  My guess is that this contributes to your colleague's desire to sign everything -- the compiler is demanding it.

---

**EDIT** Since writing this answer you can see both the pro and against camp have roughly equivalent support. There clearly isn't a right answer here.

The point that compelled this edit though is that nowadays we take so many open source libraries from NuGet, and many of them are not signed at all. If you wanted to sign your assembly, you'd need to have any dependencies signed too. Many of the open source libraries that are signed have the private keys used for signing publicly available in their source repositories.

As with everything there are trade-offs to be made. In my experience of working in private environments, the benefits of signing are mostly theoretical (or academic, as [@user289100](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2404141/24874) mentions), unless you're concerned about government agencies modifying your code in which case you need to be paranoid about so many levels of your infrastructure that signing would seem like a small amount of effort. Otherwise the amount of challenges that cascade out of having to sign everything just don't seem worth it. However your environment may have different requirements, or you may be a masochist!

See also [Teun D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363828/24874) for information on challenges related to versioning assemblies when using strong names.

Comment: Agreed, it's like a crack addiction to him now

Comment: One more point to note is if you want to share this assembly across different application then signing is a must (i.e. GAC).

Answer (score 62):

I've taken advantage of non-signed assemblies to get around issues before and in academic settings shown people why it's important. I replaced a DLL file that was unsigned (again in an academic setting) with one I made with the same name, same signatures, and used [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to copy and paste the original code, but in mine I emailed user names and passwords that were being passed in before calling 'real' code.

If signed, you can make a signature match, but not replace. Contrary to what Zippy says, there will be a run-time compliation error.

Signing assemblies is never overkill. It takes 30 seconds. It's like saying locking your doors is overkill if you live in the country. If you want to gamble with your belongings, go ahead, leave it open. It only takes one security breach to get fired. It only takes 30 seconds to sign an assembly and there's no business case not to. The performance impacts is negligable.

Comment: If a hacker can change the dll he can also change the application that calls the dll.

Comment: That is correct Zippy, but without having the key to sign the application then they will have a hard time getting the application to run in an envrionment where only the signed version of the original application is allowed to run, which would be the case in several environments I've worked in. Your missing the forest for the trees: To not sign an assembly is taking on an unneeded security risk that takes 30 seconds to avoid and there is no business case or real world case I've ever seen to not sign an assembly.

Answer (score 41):

One additional point: signing your assemblies breaks backward compatibility over versions. Your references all start to include version numbers and versions with other version numbers are considered non-compatible. This hinders upgrading to newer versions of distributed assemblies.

In my opinion, you should only code-sign assemblies if you see some concrete gain from it:

- if you deploy to environments where untrusted people might touch your assemblies
- in certain plug-in models, where you want to use the certificate as evidence for upgrading the trust
- if your code should be callable from other signed code (a project like, say log4net, justifiably signs their code to be widely usable; they messed up hugely in compatibility by losing their secret key a few years ago, another risk of code-signing).
- if you want to deploy to the GAC

Answer (score 9):

Has your colleague given you any indications as to *why* he likes to sign assemblies?  One advantage to signing that hasn't been discussed here yet is that only signed assemblies can be put in the GAC (i.e. be shared across managed processes), but the downsides do seem to outweigh the upsides from my (admittedly inexperienced) perspective.

Your anecdote about self-signing Microsoft code seems particularly suspect to me.  If MS didn't sign the code, there's probably a reason, right?  And by signing it, you're taking responsibility for it when you didn't write it - another opportunity for the future to bite you.

Comment: actually I'm not sure why but Microsoft certainly did not sign Enterprise Library 3.1

Comment: Why would sharing an assembly between processes require the assembly to be in the GAC?

Comment: It's not that you can't share runtime references to the same .dll, it's that only assemblies with strong names (i.e. signed ones) can get into the GAC - and assemblies are put in the GAC so they can be shared.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing about signing an assembly is, that one can't inject incorrect one in place of yours (also - yourself by an accident). In example, if you create a program that refers to an assembly Foo.dll, version 1.0, someone can create the an assembly, with the same version, and replace yours, when you sign your library, it won't be possible (at least I don't think it's easily possible).

Answer (score 4):

Signatures are only necessary if the assemblies are placed in the GAC, nothing else.
Signed assemblies do not prevent someone to mess with them. A hacker can still strip of the signature and any other code that checks for the signature.

Comment: For a web application, the hacker would have to also modify the web.config.

Comment: If a hacker can remove signatures from an assembly, the web.config is not going to stop them either.

Comment: Downvoters are advised to read http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2010/02/tampering-with-strong-named-assembly.html and similar articles linked from that one.

Comment: Current: yes and no. I tried, and Windows default is to NOT check the signature ("strong name"). Probably to be User Friendly :-) The referenced links show what to add to App.config to enforce signature checking. And then, contrary to the article, signature checking really works and detects any tampering, whether with version nr, or content.

Answer (score 3):

I agree it seems like a bit of a waste.  It's really needed to ensure the file is what you think it is (and hasn't been tampered with).  But if you trust the confines of your own network security and web server, then signing your web assemblies seems like a redundant step.

But maybe that's my small-business experience talking.  If you're talking about a mission-critical online banking website, then sign away.

Answer (score 2):

Think about doing it if you're going to ship something and/or actually have a reason to do it.  In every other case, it's just hassle.  I'd ask your workmate what he actually gets out of doing this.

I've encountered signed assembly-itis before and it's a pain in the posterior, especially when you consider the amount of people who have little to no knowledge of signing assemblies, what it's for and how to do it.  It's just another thing you shouldn't have to concern yourself with unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your assembly when it's used in a deploy-from-the-web [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) [XBAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML_Browser_Applications).

In addition, all referenced assemblies will need to be signed as well.

Answer (score 1):

We sign our assemblies because there are times when we get errors like the following (this one is from testing, but can occur when running the application):

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Latitude.Platform.Core, Version=1.0.5871.22518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7926214d13e12325' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

TearDown : System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Latitude.Platform.Core, Version=1.0.5871.22518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7926214d13e12325' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

We'd found that **Visual Studio gets it wrong** sometimes and **runs old code**.

If you want an error if you are running old code, then sign your assemblies.

If you are writing a **nuget** package, **please sign your assemblies**.  Unsigned assemblies is awkward for us who want to make sure we're running the latest version of our code.  **I can't fix Visual Studio**.  All I can do is detect that Visual Studio got it wrong. **So please, sign your nuget assemblies**.

Comment: Update: The tide of using unsigned assemblies is winning ;)  We're solving the problem above differently: build & test on a CI server starting from an empty or "clean"ed directory.  Maybe we have the scenario locally on our dev machines, but it's rare that it happens or doesn't have much practical impact.