# Can I sign DLLs that are not open source?

Tags: .net, dll, mvccontrib, strongname

I am trying to add portable areas into my project using MVCContrib but am having problems with the fact that the dll is unsigned.

I am now trying to sign the dll, which means I have to re-sign all the references that it uses (including Microsoft.Web.MVC) - as the Microsoft dll is not open source, for example. does that mean that I cannot sign it? As I am unable to access the source code and create a SNK key for it..

EDIT: I want to sign the assemblies because:
-After looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197133/anything-wrong-with-not-signing-a-net-assembly) it seems there are very few (good)reasons for using unsigned assemblies. 
-And I am finding that it has a knock-on effect where any assembly that references the portable area has to be unsigned, and any assembly that references that, and so on...

Comment: Why do you want to sign it? Does not really make sense unless you want it in the GAC or have a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Instructions on how to do so [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2004/12/15/772.aspx). Will leave this up in case anyone else needs it..